# SSL or TLS encryption for custom protocol

Tags: c++, networking, encryption

So I'm making my own peer-to-peer UDP protocol and I want to add encryption, so basically I want to have the clients exchange public encryption keys. What library would I use, and how would I generate the keys and use them to encrypt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSL and TLS require a reliable transport protocol and cannot run over UDP.  What you're looking for is [DTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347).  What you do from there depends on what library you use.  Wikipedia lists [several options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security#Libraries).